# Quero centralizar um table que não centraliza mesmo com align="center". O table está em negrito

Tags: html, table, css

PcWeb

```
        <td style="font-size: 60px" aling="center">
            <h1  heigth="87px" top="191px" border-radius="nullpx" style="color: #FFFFFF;" font-family="Arial">PcWeb</h1>
       
            <input type="search" placeholder=" O que procura? digite aqui..." value="" id="input-search" data-testid="input-search" font-size="1" class="entrada">

        </td>
    
        <td>
            
            <div> 
                <div class="login">
                    <img src="Perfil.png" width="43px" height="46px">
                    <h3 style="color: #B1B1B1;">Minha Conta</h3>
                    <h2 style="color: #B1B1B1;">Login/Cadastrar</h2>
                    <br>
                </div>>
                <div class="botaocarrinho"></divclass>
                   <center><h1 font-size="24px"> Carrinho </h1>
                    <img src="Carrinho.png" width="47px"; height="46px";></center> <br> <br>
                <div>  
                    
            </div>
            
        
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table style="background-color: #4F2099;" height="50px" width="100%" >
    <tr style="background-color: #4F2099; text-align: center; font-family: Kodchasan;" >

        
        <td style="background-color: #37008E" width="206px";> 
            <a class="link" href="home.html" title="Home"><h style=color:White> Home </h></a>
        </td>

        <td width="206px"; > 
            <a class="link" href="departamentos.html" title="Departamentos"><h style=color:White> Departamentos </h></a>
        </td>

        <td style="background-color: #37008E" width="206px";> 
             <a class="link" href="Games.html" title="Games"><h style=color:White> Games</h> </a>
        </td>

        <td width="206px";> 
            <a class="link" href="PC.html" title="Peças p/PC"><h style=color:White > Produtos</h></a>
        </td>

        <td style="background-color: #37008E" width="206px";> 
            <a class="link" href="Novidades.html" title="Novidades"><h style=color:White > Novidades</h></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<table  height="200px" width="100%" >
<tr >
   <td background="Banner inicial.jpg"> <center><img src="pc.png" height="300px" width="191px">   <img src="pc(2).png" height="297px" width="240px">  </center>
 
    </td>
</tr>
</table> 

<br>

**<table class="table-verde"; border="0" >**

    
    <center><tr style="background-color: #48BA12;" height="55px" width="95%" >
            <td colspan="3">
                <h style=color:White> RECOMENDADOS PARA VOCÊ!</h>
            </td>

    </tr> 

    <tr style="background-color: #000000;" height="400px" width="55%"  >

        <td>
            <h style=color:White> </h>
            <img src="Monitor colorido(2).png" width="150px" height="157px" margin-right="5px"> 
            <br> <br>
            <h style="color:#FFFFFF"> MONITOR DE PC</h>
            <br> <br>
            <h style="color:#FFFFFF"> Monitor Gamer Predator <br> XB273U NX com painel <br> wide quad HD (WQHD) <br>
                com resolução more</h>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br> <br>
        
        </td>

        <td>
            <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
             <h style="color:#FFFFFF"> <font face="Antiqua"> MESA DIGITAL </font></h> <br> <br>
             <h style="color:#FFFFFF"> Monitor Game Portátil <br> Asus Rog Strix 17,3´ <br> Full Hd Xg17ahp</h>
             <br> <br>
            <center><img src="Mesa digital (2).png"  position="absolute"; width="183px"; height="147px";> </center>
        </td>

        <td>
            <h style=color:White> </h>
            <img src="Mause branco (2).png" width="150px" height="157px" margin-right="5px"> 
            <br> <br>
            <h style="color:#FFFFFF"> MOUSE</h>
            <br> <br>
            <h style="color:#FFFFFF"> Professional Wired 
                <br>  Gaming Mouse 6 button <br>3200DPl LED Optical USB  ) <br>
             
            <br>   <br>
            <br>
            <br> 
        
        </td>
      
     </tr>

     <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="Thanos">
        <img src="NVIDIA___headpic.jpg" width="1800px" height="486px">
        </td>
     </tr>

     <tr style="background-color: #48BA12;" height="55px" width="95%" >

        <td colspan="3">
            <h style=color:White> NOVIDADES</h>
        </td>
        
     </tr>

    <br> <br> 

  </table>

    

    <table  style="background-color: #000000;" border="23" align="center" width="95%" >


       <tr>
            <td colspan="2"> 
                <br>
                <figure class="gif">
                    <img src="Gif Sonic.gif" width="869px"   height="351px">
                </figure> 
            </td>

        </tr>
        
        <tr> 

           
            
            <td>
             <figure class="gif">
             <img src="d98d46_5c45c28321b54db6931a59193768e30f_mv2.gif" width="398px" height="155px" ;  >  
             </figure>

            </td> 
            <td>
                <button class="VejaAgora"> Veja Agora!</button>

            </td> 
        
        </tr>
       
            
              
       
       
       </tr>

    </table>

    <br> <br> <br>
    <div style="background-color: #383839;"><br>
        <table cellspadding="20px" border="0" align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>

            <td width="30px" style="background-color: #383839;" ></td>
            <td width="40%">
            <nav>
                <h3 align="left" style="color: red; font-family: txt;">COMO PODEMOS AJUDAR?</h3>
                <hr align="left" heigth="50px" width="230px" color="red" size="4px">
                <li align="left" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: larger;">Entrega</li> <br>
                <li align="left" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: larger;">Garantia</li> <br>
                <li align="left" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: larger;">Como comprar</li> <br>
                <li align="left" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: larger;">Políticas de privacidade </li> <br>
                <li align="left" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: larger;">Localização</li> <br>
                <li align="left" style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: larger;">Quem somos</li> <br>
            </nav>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <img src="pagamentos.png" align="center" height="100px" width="300px"> <br><br>
                 <h2 style="color: red" >Horario de atendimento das <br> 08h as 18h (sábado das 08h - 16h) <br>
                    exeto domingos e feriados </h2>

                
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <h1 style="color: red; font-family: txt;" > Baixe nosso App</h1>
                <img src="PlayStory.png" align="center" height="75px" width="150px"> <br> <br>
                <img src="disponivel-na-app-store-botao-1.png" align="center" height="75px" width="150px"> <br>
                 <img src="Robo (2).png" align="center" height="200px" width="250px"> <br> 

            </td>
        
        </tr>

        <tr style="background-color: #636363;">
            <td width="30px" style="background-color: #636363;" ></td>

            <td >  
                <h3 style="color: white;"><img src="whatsapp.png" align="center" height="60px" width="60px"> (19) 99185-7845 // (19) 99432-8732 </h3>

            </td>

            <td>  
                <h3 style="color: white;"><img src="Instagran.png" align="center" height="60px" width="60px"> PcWebOfc </h3>

            </td>

            <td>  
                <h3 style="color: white;"><img src="Facebook.png" align="center" height="90px" width="90px"> PcWebOfc 
                    <!-- <img src="Robo (2).png" align="center" height="200px" width="250px">--> </h3> 


            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score -3):

Você pode centralizar horizontalmente um table adicionando
`style="margin: auto;` ao seu css. Apenas se atente ao tamanho dos `<tr>` e `<img>` com tamanhos já configurados.